# Jira workflow validator - how to retrieve value of issue field from workflow screen

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am writing a jira  Workflow validator plugin  - inside validate method I want to get  value of  a custom issue field , provided by workflow screen (workflow screen pops up while doing workflow transition)

Note I  want to get field value from workflow scree and not by issue - this code does not serve purpose - customField.getValue(issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the HTTP Request can be done with code such as

```
 HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    if (request == null) {
    log.warn("Unable to find a request while creating an issue");
    return;
    }

    String[] values = request.getParameterValues("mykey");
    if (values == null || values.length != 1) {
    log.debug("Unable to find parameters in the request while creating an issue");
    return;
    }

    String valueString = values[0];
    if (valueString == null || valueString.equals("")) {
    // Valid if no value was entered
    log.debug("Unable to find a value for mykey while creating an issue");
    return;
    }
```

Also check out the chapter on this in my book O'Reilly book "Practical JIRA Plugins".